# How to jump to the page which contains a certain piece of data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've a table which uses jQuery DataTables plugin. So am adding new row dynamically by using the code below:

```js
 var oTable = $('#table_question').DataTable();

 var row = oTable.row.add([5, "My Question", 45,]).node();

 oTable.row(row).draw(false);
```

The page length of my datatable is 10, so when I add more that 10 rows, pagination occurs and the next rows getting inserted into page 2 of the datatable. So user will not get any feel of new row inserted.

How can I jump to next page automatically if the new row is on that page other than the active page?

Comment: This would work (if you knew the row data): [http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData()](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`page.jumpToData()`](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData()) plug-in to jump to a page by searching for data from a column.

Ideally you need to pick a column containing unique values. In the example below, person's name is used with data and column indexes equal to `0` (zero-based index).

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'page.jumpToData()', function ( data, column ) {
    var pos = this.column(column, {order:'current'}).data().indexOf( data );

    if ( pos >= 0 ) {
        var page = Math.floor( pos / this.page.info().length );
        this.page( page ).draw( false );
    }

    return this;
} );

$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    var data = ["Joe Smith","System Architect","Edinburgh","5421","2011/04/25","$320,800"];

    var row = table.row.add(data).node();
    table.row(row).draw(false);

    // Use first column (index - 0) with Name to locate data in the table
    table.page.jumpToData(data[0], 0);
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tk295cb/1/) for code and demonstration.